# Load an HTTPS URL by iframe in html page

Tags: html, css, node.js, asp.net-core, electron

I have this project which is an HTML page and wanted to load an HTTPS URL by iframe, How can I do so?

I get this error:
Refused to frame 'https://www.google.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'frame-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have a Content Security Policy defined for your app.
You need to add `frame-src: https://www.google.com` to the CSP header to allow iframes with that domain.
Since you have not defined a frame-src in the header, it is falling back to default-src, which doesn't specify the domain either, so it gets blocked.

Comment: How can I define a `iframe-src` in the header? (and by header you mean the HTML page header right?)

Comment: No I mean an HTTP header, your server is returning it in the response. A CSP can also be defined in head->meta if I recall correctly though

Comment: I used `frame-src` on header of my HTML page now I get this error :

Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set `X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

Comment: Ahh that's set by Google :) That means you can't put their page in an iframe. They have forbidden it.

Comment: so I have to configure my asp core project in order to put it in my iframe.
Thanks ;)